# URL is not a recognised format, can I convert

Tags: c#, azure

I want to display an image stored as a string in database table. When I run the code I get the error "Invalid URI, format could not be determined". Within the table the actual string is something like this:13d2dr09-377-423c-993e-22db3l390b66

How do I convert this so it can be recognised.

```
                string sAdImageUrl = myReader.GetString(3);

                var image = new BitmapImage();
                int BytesToRead = 100;

                WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create(new Uri(sAdImageUrl,UriKind.Absolute));                   
                request.Timeout = -1;
                WebResponse response = request.GetResponse();
                Stream responseStream = response.GetResponseStream();
                BinaryReader reader = new BinaryReader(responseStream);
                MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

                byte[] bytebuffer = new byte[BytesToRead];
                int bytesRead = reader.Read(bytebuffer, 0, BytesToRead);

                while (bytesRead > 0)
                {
                    memoryStream.Write(bytebuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                    bytesRead = reader.Read(bytebuffer, 0, BytesToRead);
                }

                image.BeginInit();
                memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

                image.StreamSource = memoryStream;
                image.EndInit();

                imaPartners.Source = image;

            }
        }
```

Comment: 13d2dr09-377-423c-993e-22db3l390b66 is not a uri.

Comment: @Is the data type in your database `binary`? You need to store the Uri as a string.

Comment: Seems like some pieces to this puzzle are missing.  What does that string represent?  It's not a URI by itself.  Should you be appending it to a base URI path, and possibly appending an image type extension?  I would suggest you figure out what the URI really should be by typing examples into a browser's address bar.

Comment: Yes its storing the name of the blob, can this be called in a similar way?

Comment: @user2631662 what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: [Garbage-in, garbage-out](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_In,_Garbage_Out)... Please figure out what is stored in that field and change code accordingly... My random guess would be it is part of some predefined url (if code written by someone else).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, based on your question and a comment in another answer, it sounds like you have the blob name but not the full URI. The full blob uri is going to be

```
http(s)://<cloudstorageaccountname>.blob.core.windows.net/<containername>/<blobname>
```

Since you're already working with a container object, you must have already acquired the storage account name (probably from one of your app settings), as well as your container name (since you already have a container object).

At this point, you should easily be able to assemble the full name. Note that you can choose either http or https. If you're connecting from your web/app tier straight to storage, go with http as traffic stays within the data center. If, on the other hand, you're creating links to embed in a web page to the end-user, you should consider https if the data is in any way sensitive.

You can easily get to the full Uri through the `CloudBlockBlob` object representing your blob. As a quick example, here's a snippet of a console app demonstrating this:

```
        var connString = CloudConfigurationManager.GetSetting("connectionString");
        CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(connString);

        CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();
        var container = blobClient.GetContainerReference("images");
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("fr7_20_2013110753_jpg.jpg");
        var uri = blob.Uri;
        Console.WriteLine(uri);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

And the output:

[image: full url]

Comment: Thanks, but I am getting an error 404 not found, it is being stored in the table as per blob:https://********.blob.core.windows.net/image/0d3f5611-b97e-411a-8979-7a20afb77ea6